# Why did I get [object HTMLParagraphElement] for value of variable(geolocation)

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, local-storage

Here is the code which will get users coordinate and save  the coordinates in local storage but it displaying  [object HTML Paragraph Element] as stored value
if i can save it as  numeric value it would be easy to export
i am a newbee please help me to  solve this problem

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var k = document.getElementById("demon");

localStorage.setItem("cor",k);

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";

  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
 k.innerHTML =position.coords.latitude
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demon"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage only stores items as string values. So

```
localStorage.setItem("cor",k);
```

converts `k` (an HTMLParagraphElement) to a string, " [object HTML Paragraph Element]" in your browser, and saves it as item "cor".

To save the coordinates, try converting them to a JSON string, *after obtaining them in the `showPosition` callback*, by calling `JSON.stringify` with a coordinate object as argument:

```
function showPosition(position) {
  const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
  // save in local storage:
  localStorage.setItem("cor",JSON.stringify({latitude, longitude});
  // as posted:
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + longitude;
  k.innerHTML =position.coords.latitude
   
}
```

To read the coordinates back again, pass the string value of `getItem("cor")` to `JSON.parse` to re-create the `{latitude, longitude}` object.